# Closest Linux equivalent to Windows' CreateThreadpoolTimer

Tags: windows, linux, porting

What's the closest equivalent on Linux to Windows's [`CreateThreadpoolTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: I doubt if there's such a thing as a thread pool in linux...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing about Windows, but with [`timer_create`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/timer_create) you can have several timers. And many libraries also give you timers, e.g. [QTimer](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtimer.html) in Qt (which can also give your thread pools).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [`setitimer()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setitimer)? You only get one set of interval timers per process, though.